# Set initial label in Angular UI dropdown list

Tags: angularjs

[In this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cjEKaBp0PwE53osLl1kR?p=preview) I'm trying to get the selection of a list of dropdown lists. The problem is that the dropdowns appear empty (no labels are selected by default, as set in the controller). How to fix this?

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('ctl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.rows = [ {selection: "Sel 1"}, {selection: "Sel 2"} ];

    $scope.selectItem = function(ev,index) {
        var sel = ev.target.textContent;
        $scope.lastSelection = index + " - " + sel;
        $scope.rows[index].selection = sel;
    };

});
```

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">      
      <td>
          <div class="btn-group" uib-dropdown>
            <button id="btn-append-to-body" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" uib-dropdown-toggle="">
                  {{selection}} <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" ng-click="selectItem($event,$index)" uib-dropdown-menu="" role="menu" aria-labelledby="btn-append-to-body">
               <li role="menuitem">
                  <a href="#" data-value="1" >The first item</a>
                </li>
                <li role="menuitem">
                  <a href="#" data-value="2">Another item</a>
                </li>
                <li role="menuitem">
                  <a href="#" data-value="3">Yet another item</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <br/>

  Last selection: {{lastSelection}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the row element in your binding

`{{row.selection}}` instead of `{{selection}}`

http://plnkr.co/edit/Q5YnByLUKmjkpet2gKWC?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

there is the console error: i is not deifned, 
solution is:

```
$scope.selectItem = function(ev,index) {
    var sel = ev.target.textContent;
    $scope.lastSelection = index + " - " + sel;
};
```

also edit button `{{row.selection}}` .

here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SUko3Ewj7j81N0mjkW6H?p=preview) code without errors.

Comment: @ps0604 I update my answer and wrote correct syntax to plunker, please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;)

In `app.js` replace

```
$scope.lastSelection = i + " - " + sel;
```

with

```
$scope.lastSelection = index + " - " + sel;
```

And in `index.html` replace

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu="" role="menu" aria-labelledby="btn-append-to-body" ng-click="selectItem($event,$index)">
   <li role="menuitem">
     <a href="#" data-value="1" >The first item</a>
    </li>
    <li role="menuitem">
      <a href="#" data-value="2">Another item</a>
    </li>
    <li role="menuitem">
      <a href="#" data-value="3">Yet another item</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

with

```
 <ul class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu="" role="menu" aria-labelledby="btn-append-to-body">
   <li role="menuitem">
     <a href="#" data-value="1" ng-click="selectItem($event,$index)" >The first item</a>
    </li>
    <li role="menuitem">
      <a href="#" data-value="2" ng-click="selectItem($event,$index)" >Another item</a>
    </li>
    <li role="menuitem">
      <a href="#" data-value="3" ng-click="selectItem($event,$index)" >Yet another item</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```